# How do you use ranorex with python?

Tags: python, testing, python.net, gui-testing, ranorex

It seems that [Ranorex stopped support for python with version 3.x](https://www.ranorex.com/forum/sooo-what-s-the-story-with-ironpython-t2565.html), which was back in 2011. I only found old documentation about how to use it with IronPython.

Can you provide a minimal example how to get ranorex running, best would be in standard CPython (and not IronPython)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news: Ranorex still works with `.NET for Python`. And this will still be in the future as long as C# or VB APIs are supported by ranorex and as long as [dotnet for python](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) is still supported (which it is, last commit is a few days ago at the time of this post).

Now, it is a bit tricky to get Ranorex remote control running in Python. This setup was from pure trial-and-error and combining different pieces of information online:

1. Install python for .net: `pip3 install pythonnet`
2. Find out the DLL folder of ranorex. In my case it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ranorex 8.0\Bin\x64\`. In this folder you should see several DLLs (75 DLLs on my machine) including `Ranorex.Core.dll`

Now Ranorex should be ready to be used in Python. Here is a small example (you'd need to replace the `sys.path.extend()` with the path you got from step 2.

```
import sys
import clr

# make Ranorex module available, needs before the `import Ranorex`
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Ranorex 8.0\\Bin\\x64\\')
clr.AddReference('Ranorex.Core') 
import Ranorex

Ranorex.Host.Local.RunApplication('C:\\path\\to\\my_app.exe')

apps = [c for c in Ranorex.Host.Local.Children if "My App" in c.ToString()]
if len(apps) != 1:
    print("starting of 'My App' somehow failed, quitting now")
    sys.exit(1)

app = apps[0]
app.PressKeys('{LMenu down}{Fkey}{LMenu up}') # presses Alt-F -> e.g. opens the file menu
```

To develop your python scripts you best set up the test in ranorex recorder and then generate the C# code over `Export` -> `Generate C# Code (Ctrl-G)`. Then you'd need to translate the C# code to python but that's relatively easy.

Comment: you can just add the paths that contain Ranorex DLLs to `sys.path`.

Comment: @denfromufa: thanks for the hint, I've adapted my answer now. A lot simpler and also more clean this way